# php zip installation on linux

Tags: php, zip

```
>pecl install zip
```

got the following error:

```
checking for the location of zlib... configure: error: zip support requires ZLIB.
Use --with-zlib-dir=<DIR> to specify prefix where ZLIB include and library are located
```

what does this mean?

Answer (score 15):

The PHP zip functionality relies on the ZLIB libary, you need to install it first.

Comment: on ubuntu: `apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

Comment: I was looking in apt and I did have the normal zlib1g (minus -dev) I thought it was the correct installation... I installed the one you recommended and all fine. Just for my info, what is the difference between libraries and their -dev version?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your PHP installation wasn't compiled with zlib support. You may have to reconfigure PHP. From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.installation.php):

> Zlib support in PHP is not enabled by default. You will need to configure PHP --with-zlib[=DIR]

Comment: would I use php-config for this? does this require a rebuild of php?

Comment: @wo_ I'm not a Linux sysadmin so I don't really know. `php-config` sounds good though, if that can take a `--with-zlib=...` argument you may already be there.

Comment: @wo_ possibly helpful: http://forums.techguy.org/linux-unix/312393-build-php-zlib-support.html